# vba MID function makes my apostrohes invisible

Tags: excel, vba

I am running a loop in my vba module and using the vba function `MID` to write text input into a message box to a range of cells.
The problem is when the loop processes an apostrophe in a word such as "Don't",
it makes the apostrophe invisible in the cell.
What changes do I need to make in my code for the apostrophes to be visible?

Here is the problematic snip-it concerned:

```
For CounterTxt = 1 To textLngt
    chaseEnd = chaseEnd + 1

    For CounterChase = chaseBeg To chaseEnd - 1 Step -1  ' reduces the chase length by 1 after each repition
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, CounterChase + 1).Value = ""   ' deleats previous chase position while running.
        Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, CounterChase).Value = Mid(MyText, CounterTxt, 1)
        Sleep 1 / 2 '1 millisecond pause
    Next CounterChase
Next CounterTxt
```

Comment: You mean `Mid` function I suppose? Not `Dim` statement?

Comment: Yes sorry Mid is what I mean

Comment: In each loop check if the first character is an apostrophe, if it is then double it up so it outputs `''` rather than just `'`.

Comment: Thanks will check if this works.

Answer (score 1):

An apostrophe is a 'hidden code' that tells Excel that it is text. You can just precede **all** outputs to the cell with an apostrophe and it will work fine:

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(7, CounterChase).Value = "'" & Mid(MyText, CounterTxt, 1)
```

Comment: Smart-a**e :p    You're right - was thinking too much into it with my answer. +1

Comment: It's useful in case there are numerics within the string, forcing them to stay in the format they've been entered and never attempt to evaluate them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to double-up your apostrophe when it arrives at the start of the text string.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyText As String
    Dim x As Long

    MyText = "Don't stop me now, I'm having such a good time."

    For x = 1 To Len(MyText)

'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

'        If Mid(MyText, x, 1) = "'" Then
'            Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) = "'" & Mid(MyText, x)
'        Else
'            Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) = Mid(MyText, x)
'        End If
'''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
'       or you can do it this way

        Sheet1.Cells(x, 1) = IIf(Mid(MyText, x, 1) = "'", "'", "") & Mid(MyText, x)
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Darren, Works great!. I'v been pulling my hair out for hours with this damn invisible apostrophe.

Comment: The answer given by @CLR is probably better - just add an apostrophe in front each time as it gets removed anyway.... if there's no apostrophe just add one and it gets removed, if there is an apostrophe it gets doubled up and the first one gets removed.